# Should it be "without scarf" or "without a scarf"?

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-article, zero-article

Is one of these right and one wrong, and if so, which is which and why?

1. Sandra is the woman without scarf.
2. Sandra is the woman without **a** scarf.

Would it work the same if we said she was without gloves, without sunscreen, without hat, without pity, without haste?

Answer (score 1):

*Sandra is the woman without **a** scarf.* Is the correct sentence because 'scarf' needs an article (like a or the) in front of it.